# integrate pentaho community with hadoop

Tags: hadoop, pentaho

i want to integrate hadoop to pentaho data-integration,I found on pentaho site, in that site there is pentaho for hadoop, but it's commercial.i want to make my data-integration community edtion to integrate with hadoop.
How i can solve this ?

Tks

Answer (score 2):

In New version(PDI 4.2.0), you can see hadoop components In PDI.

visit: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/

Answer (score 1):

Actually since PDI 4.3.0 ( which got released yesterday ) all the hadoop stuff is now included in the open source version!  So just go straight to sourceforge and download! All the docs are on infocenter.pentaho.com

Answer (score 1):

The most recent work for integrating Kettle (ETL) with Hadoop and other various NoSQL data stores can be found in the [Pentaho Big Data Plugin](http://ci.pentaho.com/job/pentaho-big-data-plugin/). This is a Kettle plugin and provides connectors to HDFS, MapReduce, HBase, Cassandra, MongoDB, CouchDB that work across many Pentaho products: Pentaho Data Integration, Pentaho Reporting, and the Pentaho BA Server. The code is hosted on Github: https://github.com/pentaho/big-data-plugin.

There's a community landing page with more information on the Pentaho Wiki. You'll find How To guides, configuration options, and documentation for the Java Developer here: http://community.pentaho.com/bigdata